# How can i merge joins?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have the following query which works but i would like to improve (performance wise):

.`sentence_id` and .`project_id` are indexes.

My goal now is to try to merge the 2 joins on the same tables into a single one (if possible)
How can i do that ?

```
SELECT rs.project_id,
               ms.id AS raw_sentence_id,
               rs.sentence AS raw_sentence_text,
               rs.sentence_id AS raw_sentence_text_id,
               rst.tokens AS tokenization_information,
               ns.sentence_id AS normalized_sentence_id,
               ns.sentence AS normalized_sentence_text,
               nst.token_indices
          FROM manual_sentences ms
          JOIN sentences rs ON (ms.original_sentence_id = rs.sentence_id AND rs.project_id = 623483)
     LEFT JOIN sentence_tokens rst ON (ms.original_sentence_id = rst.sentence_id AND rst.project_id = 623483)
          JOIN sentences ns ON (ms.sentence_id = ns.sentence_id AND ns.project_id = 623483)
     LEFT JOIN sentence_tokens nst ON (ms.sentence_id = nst.sentence_id AND nst.project_id = 623483)
     WHERE ms.project_id = 623483
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using a conjunction:

```
SELECT rs.project_id,
               ms.id AS raw_sentence_id,
               rs.sentence AS raw_sentence_text,
               rs.sentence_id AS raw_sentence_text_id,
               rst.tokens AS tokenization_information,
               ns.sentence_id AS normalized_sentence_id,
               ns.sentence AS normalized_sentence_text,
               nst.token_indices
          FROM manual_sentences ms
          JOIN sentences rs ON (ms.original_sentence_id = rs.sentence_id AND rs.project_id = 623483)
     LEFT JOIN sentence_tokens rst ON (ms.original_sentence_id = rst.sentence_id AND ms.sentence_id = rst.sentence_id AND rst.project_id = 623483)
          JOIN sentences ns ON (ms.sentence_id = ns.sentence_id AND ns.project_id = 623483)
     WHERE ms.project_id = 623483
```

Comment: ms.original_sentence_id and ms.sentence_id  can be different. And when they are i need information from 2 separate rows

Comment: Well in that case I think you will need two joins.